# Creating a secure .Net WebAPI for Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, security, authorization, token

I have created a Custom Web API using .net C# that will be called in my sharepoint online and i was wondering if is there is anything i could use from sharepoint and use it in my WebApi to verify that this request comes from an authorized user?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use ADAL to authenticate using OAuth2.

You have to register an app on Azure Active Directory to create an endpoint for authentication, then you can use [ADAL.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js) to get a valid token and send it on header of http calls to your Web API.

Comment: How would i verify the token that i get from ADAL from my web api?

Comment: Here one possible implementation: https://blogs.msmvps.com/windsor/2017/03/12/walkthrough-building-a-custom-web-api-for-use-with-sharepoint-online/ (look for GetSharePointAccessToken method)

Comment: ive manage to do this but since there was an update im stuck at the issue regarding "AADSTS240002" same as everyone and Rob hasn't found any workaround for this yet